# Whats the connection between the browser and the Internet?

Tags: browser

How does a browser fit in to the internet? The router connects you to the ISP servers and then you get connected to the internet, correct? How does the browser take your computer and relate it to the internet?

Comment: the internet is a network using the [server-client architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model), the browser in this respect is the client. Apart from that the browser is a specific client for the HTTP protocol of the internet. Of course modern browsers can handle more protocols like FTP and also can communicate with more options like websockets etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser is, in the most basic sense, a web page renderer.
It's main job is to retrieve a page (usually a HTML text file) from the web and display it to you so you can interact with that page. Inside the HTML there can be references to images and scripts, and the browser manages them for you.
Example: You want to access the StackOverflow page.

Step 1: You type the adress in the browser (http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Step 2: The browser converts the adress to a IP adress (using DNS services), and then sends a HTTP request to that IP

Step 3: The page is retrieved

Step 4: The browser parses the page and retrieves any images or files required by that page (all through HTTP requests)

Step 5: The browser renders the page and shows it in your screen

Step 6: When you click in a link, the browser sends another HTTP request and the the process starts again

HTTP is not the only protocol used in the web, I used it for the sake of simplicity.

If you want to understand the "how" of all that, you would have to study computer languages and programming.

I suggest you to read these pages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser